# go modules multiple main methods

Tags: go, go-modules

I have a project with mutliple main methods.
When running `go build program1/main1.go` which has a different set of dependencies than `program2/main2.go`, my first `go build` seems to alter my `go.mod` file and removes the dependencies it *thinks* it does not need. Yet `main2` would need these dependencies.

I've tried using `go build ...` but that also created a different set of dependencies. Specifically, it seems like all the `//indirect` dependencies get removed and cause program2 to fail.

Is there a way of running `go build` or `go run` without updating the `go.mod` file? Using `go build -mod=readonly program1/main1.go` it tells me that it fails because the dependencies need to be updated..

Comment: If two things do _not_ have the same dependencies and each should have it's own go.mod. The go.mod contains _the_ dependencies and not just _some_ (read "unrelated", "old", and "copy-past-leftovers") dependencies.

Comment: Your life will be much simpler if you able to only working with one module at a time, so you don't want to needlessly cut up what could be a single module. If you do split them out into separate modules with individual go.mod files, it is more work. That said, there is an overview of the [new Go 1.18 workspace feature in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71622805/11210494). Workspaces make it easier to handle editing multiple modules at once. Separately, this [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57314494/11210494) has a good overview of how to organize a module in general.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you're looking for *submodules*. See [this walktrhough](https://github.com/go-modules-by-example/index/tree/master/009_submodules).

TLDR: you'll want a separate `go.mod` in each of your tools's `cmd` dir, and you can use the `replace` directive to point dependncies from these tools to your local module.

[This Go Issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/27542) and others linked from it suggest that figuring out "the one right way" to do this is still WIP, though I think your use case is simple enough.

Comment: Yeah, eventually that's what I did :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using submodules is a way to nest multiple Go module projects you can *edit*.

But Go 1.18 might include the notion of **Go workspace**, which means you don't need submodules anymore: *one* Go project can include multiple modules you can edit.

See [`golang/go` issue 45713: "proposal: `cmd/go`: add a workspace mode "](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/45713) and its [design document](https://go.googlesource.com/proposal/+/master/design/45713-workspace.md).

> ### Background
>
> Users often want to make changes across multiple modules: for instance, to introduce a new interface in a package in one module along with a usage of that interface in another module.
>
> Normally, the `go` command recognizes a single "`main`" module the user can edit.
> Other modules are read-only and are loaded from the module cache.
>
> The `go mod replace` directive is the exception: it allows users to replace the resolved version of a module with a working version on disk.
> But working with the `replace` directive can often be awkward: each module developer might have working versions at different location on disk, so having the directive in a file that needs to be distributed with the module isn't a good fit for all use cases.
>
> ### Proposal
>
> This proposal describes a new workspace mode in the `go` command for editing multiple modules.
>
> The presence of a **`go.work`** file in the working directory or a containing directory will put the `go` command into **workspace mode**.
> The `go.work` file specifies a set of local modules that comprise a workspace. When invoked in workspace mode, the `go` command will always select these modules and a consistent set of dependencies.
>
> **Main modules**: The module the user is working in.
> Before this proposal, this is the single module containing the directory where the `go` command is invoked. This module is used as the starting point when running MVS.
> **This proposal proposes allowing multiple main modules**.

See for instance [CL 334934](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/334934/) (CL = Change List)

> ### [`dev.cmdgo`] `cmd/go`: add the workspace mode
>
> This change adds the outline of the implementation of the workspace mode.
>
> The `go` command will now locate `go.work` files, and read them to determine
> which modules are in the workspace.
> It will then put those modules in the root of the workspace when building the build list.
> It supports building, running, testing, and listing in workspaces.

You can initiate a multiple-module project with [`go mod initwork`](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/334936/)

Again, this is not before Go 1.18 (Q1 2022) and will probably be opt-in in Go 1.19 (Q3 2022).