# Goland : Puting multiple projects into one workspace

Tags: go, goland

**Problem**

I am working on a large project that has so many child projects, and *I put them under one folder*, let's say folder `A`, and opened folder `A` on Goland. Which looked perfect at first, However, the go.mod of each project became all red and I noticed that all dependencies were unresolved...

**Question**

I marked each child project as "Resource Root", but it didn't help, and to my surprise there was an empty "External Libraries" in the `A` folder, it has nothing but Go SDK 1.6.
But `A` folder was nothing but a folder for my projects!
What can I do to fix these dependencies missing problem?

By the way, the projects are using vendoring.

**My Guess**

Probably the issue was that I moved all projects from $GOPATH/src to $GOPATH/src/A.

Comment: Two options: A) Add replace directoves to your go.mod files. B) Wait for Go 1.18 which introduces workspaces via a toplevel go.work file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple modules within the same project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55041915/multiple-modules-within-the-same-project)

Answer (score 0):

GoLand supports multiple projects in a single folder. You just have to update your IDE.

This should work:[image]

And this should work as well: [image]

Answer (score 0):

When you want open another project by selecting `(File > Open > My_PROJECT_FOLDER)` you get this window:

As you see it, the choice is yours:

If you choose:

**`Cancel` - Cancel your action.**

**`Attach` - Attach your project next to another.**

**`New Window` - Opens your project in a new window leaving the old one in the current window .**

**`This Window` - Closes the old project opens a new one**.

[image]

**In your case you must choose : `Attach`**