# Creating a project with Go modules

Tags: go, go-modules

I'm trying to understand Go modules and create a simple hello world program. Go version: `1.16.2`

```
/project1
/project1/main.go
/project1/helpers/helpers.go
```

`helpers.go` will contain some utility method like:

```
package ???

import "fmt"

func DoSomething() {
  fmt.Println("Doing something in helpers.go")
}
```

`main.go` will use methods from `helpers.go` like this:

```
package main

import "??"

func main() {
  helpers.DoSomething()
}
```

VSCode is not allowing me to do this and has a red underline on `helpers`.

What am I missing here? How can I achieve this?

---

Edit 1: Adding go.mod and package names:

So I ran `go mod init helpers` in `/helpers` folder and came out with this:

```
/project1/helpers/helpers.go
/project1/helpers/go.mod
```

go.mod

```
module helpers

go 1.16
```

My `main.go` now looks like this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "helpers"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("blah")
    helpers.DoHelperMethod()
}
```

Comment: What's up with the question marks? Can you please update those to whatever is in the actual code? Does your module have a go.mod file? If so, where is it? Can you share its contents?

Comment: Nothing I put in the ?? seems to make a difference hence I thought that was the issue and looking for hints from the internet :) For discussion, let's say they're both set to "helpers". I don't plan on uploading this code so a FQ GitHub.com URL doesn't make sense here.

No go.mod file yet. I assume I actually need 2? One at the `/helpers` folder level and one a the `main.go` level as these will be 2 different modules?

Comment: The tutorial [How To Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code) goes through the steps of writing a program like the one in the question.  The question asks about multiple modules, but a single module with multiple packages is a better fit for the code in the question.

Comment: No you only need one go.mod file per project and that file should be in the root of the project, and go source files inside the `helpers` package should all start with `package helpers` not `package ???` (that ain't even a valid package name). And the import statements for the `helpers` package should look like the following `import "<module_name>/helpers`.

Comment: Thanks @mkopriva that gave me the breakthrough I needed. I had it in my mind that I needed two modules but I see now that it's two packages inside on module. I think starting here might be a good start for me! https://golang.org/doc/tutorial/getting-started

Comment: With Go 1.18/1.19, and the notion of [Go workspace mode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68420398/6309), you could use *multiple* `go.mod` in the *same* Go project.

Answer (score 5):

Your project should have only one `go.mod` file and it should be in the root of the project. You can `cd` into the project's directory and do `go mod init <module_name>` where `<module_name>` in your case can be `project1`.

For example, once you've initialized the module, your project should look something like the following:

```
/project1/helpers/helpers.go
/project1/main.go
/project1/go.mod
```

`go.mod`

```
module project1

go 1.16
```

`main.go`

```golang
package main

import "project1/helpers"

func main() { helpers.DoHelperMethod() }
```

`helpers/helpers.go`

```golang
package helpers

func DoHelperMethod() {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: To the point answer. Thanks a lot.Btw, I read on internet that general.convention for module_name is to be like, github.com/username/project_name.

Comment: @Mandroid github.com/username/project_name is just an example of the convention. The [official reference](https://go.dev/ref/mod#module-path) says: *"A module path should describe both what the module does **and where to find it**. Typically, a module path consists of a repository root path, a directory within the repository (usually empty), and a major version suffix (only for major version 2 or higher)."*

Answer (score 0):

In case if you want to create new module follow below steps:

1. first create folder

mkdir newPackage

2. go into that folder

cd newPackage

3. Create mod init

go mod init example.com/mypackage

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XyWV.png)